# How to view log output using docker-compose run?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I use `docker-compose up` I can see logs for all containers in my `docker-compose.yml` file.

However, when I use `docker-compose run app` I only see console output for `app` but none of the services that `app` depends on. How can see log output for the other services?

Comment: You can use `docker-compose logs -f service_name`

Comment: Also note that `docker-compose run` creates new container each time you execute it.

Comment: Im running `docker-compose run` in circleci just to run my tests so its okay if it creates a new container. The main issue is just not seeing log output from the dependent services.

Comment: i'm confused, how does one see the logs for containers inside docker-compose.yml file? Logs get written to that file?

Answer (score 270):

At the time of writing this the `docker-compose run` command does not provide a switch to see the logs of other services, hence you need to use the `docker-compose logs` command to see the logs you want.

## Update June 10th 2022

As commented by @Sandburg docker compose is now integrated into docker. As described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#compose-v2-and-the-new-docker-compose-command) most of the **docker compose commands** can be **called** the same way just **without the hyphen**. So **docker compose** instead of **docker-compose**:

> The new Compose V2, which supports the compose command as part of the Docker CLI, is now available.

> Compose V2 integrates compose functions into the Docker platform, continuing to support most of the previous docker-compose features and flags. You can run Compose V2 by replacing the hyphen (-) with a space, using docker compose, instead of docker-compose.

## Update July 1st 2019

```
docker-compose logs <name-of-service>
```

for all services

```
docker-compose logs
```

Use the following options from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/):

> Usage: logs [options] [SERVICE...]

> Options:

> --no-color          Produce monochrome output.

> -f, --follow        Follow log output.

> -t, --timestamps    Show timestamps.

> --tail="all"        Number of lines to show from the end of the logs
> for each container.

## See docker logs

You can start Docker compose in detached mode and attach yourself to the logs of **all container** later. If you're done watching logs you can detach yourself from the logs output **without** shutting down your services.

1. Use `docker-compose up -d` to **start all services in detached mode** (`-d`) (you won't see any logs in detached mode)
2. Use `docker-compose logs -f -t` to **attach** yourself to the logs of **all running services**, whereas `-f` means you follow the log output and the `-t` option gives you timestamps (See [Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/))
3. Use `Ctrl + z` or `Ctrl + c` to **detach** yourself from the log output **without** shutting down your running containers

If you're interested in logs of a single container you can use the `docker` keyword instead:

1. Use `docker logs -t -f <name-of-service>`

---

## Save the output

To save the output to a file you add the following to your logs command:

1. `docker-compose logs -f -t >> myDockerCompose.log`

Comment: I don't know why this is the accepted answer. Question was about docker-compose run and a lot of times you run that with -rm so there are no logs. I would like to see output of shell script as i'm running it.

Comment: While this is useful info, this is NOT an answer to the question. As @JamesO'Brien said, the question is about `docker-compose run` and attaching to those services, which have unique names from the services listed in `docker.compose.yml`

Comment: I think that there is a critical thing that is missing in every piece of documentation that I've seen: the container instance launched by `docker-compose run` doesn't count as a "service", as meant by docker-compose. `docker-compose logs` only prints the logs of "services". This is why you can't print the logs of the main command using `docker-compose logs`, so if you use `docker-compose run -d`, you can only check the logs of the main job using `docker logs` (not `compose`) command.

Comment: `docker-compose` has been integrated in docker and replaced by `docker compose` without dash.

Comment: `docker-compose logs -f -t` works only within the directory containing the docker-compose.yaml

Comment: `docker compose`  without hyphen needs to be activated up to the current docker version 23.0.2 [Evolution of Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-v2/)

Comment: @HansRatzinger thanks for your comment. I couldn't find any hint about the activation of `docker compose` without a hyphen in the linked documentation. Could you further explain, please? I'm thinking about improving my answer if I can point to the documentation.

Comment: @BrunoBieri thanks for your question. May be this will give a better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64907243/11634713

Answer (score 49):

If you want to see output **logs from all the services** in your terminal.

```
docker-compose logs -t -f --tail <no of lines>
```

> Eg.: 
>    Say you would like to log output of last 5 lines from all service
>
> `docker-compose logs -t -f --tail 5`

If you wish to **log output from specific services** then it can be done as below:

```
docker-compose logs -t -f --tail <no of lines> <name-of-service1> <name-of-service2> ... <name-of-service N>
```

> Usage:
>
> Eg. say you have API and portal services then you can do
>   something like below :
>
> `docker-compose logs -t -f --tail 5 portal api`
>
> Where 5 represents last 5 lines from both logs.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/

Comment: Another tip, you can emit the `--tail` flag to get all of the logs.

Answer (score 15):

1. use the command to start containers in detached mode:
   `docker-compose up -d`
2. to view the containers use: `docker ps`
3. to view logs for a container: `docker logs <containerid>`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately we need to run `docker-compose logs` separately from `docker-compose run`. In order to get this to work reliably we need to suppress the `docker-compose run` exit status then redirect the log and exit with the right status.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
docker-compose run app | tee app.log || failed=yes
docker-compose logs --no-color > docker-compose.log
[[ -z "${failed:-}" ]] || exit 1
```

Comment: Is there a windows equivalent of the above?

Comment: @Espresso, sure. `(docker-compose --verbose up | Tee-Object build.log) || ($env:FAILED='yes')`. I cannot answer in full, since that would require threading. I don't think it's worth emulating bash's pipefail. Take a look instead at `Start-TreadJob` and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-6.0