# How to see error logs when docker-compose fails

Tags: error-handling, docker-compose

I have a docker image that starts the entrypoint.sh script

This script checks if the project is well configured

If everything is correct,
the container starts 
otherwise I received this error:

```
echo "Danger! bla bla bla"
exit 1000
```

Now if i start the container in this mode:

```
docker-compose up
```

i see the error correctly:

```
Danger! bla bla bla
```

but i need to launch the container in daemon mode:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

How can I show the log only in case of error?

Answer (score 22):

The **-d** flag in `docker-compose up -d` stands for **detached mode** and not deamon mode.

In **detached mode**, your service(s) (e.g. container(s)) runs in the background of your terminal. **You can't see logs in this mode.**

To see all service(s) logs you need to run this command :

```
docker-compose logs -f
```

The **-f** flag stands for "Follow log output". 
This will output all the logs for each running service you have in your `docker-compose.yml`

From my understanding you want to fire up your service(s) with :

```
docker-compose up -d
```

In order to let service(s) run in the background and have a clean console output.

And you want to print out only the errors from the logs, to do so add a pipe operator and search for error with the grep command :

```
docker-compose logs | grep error
```

This will output all the errors logged by a docker service(s).

You'll find the official documentation related to the `docker-compose up` command [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) and to the `logs` command [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/). More info on logs-handling in this [article](https://medium.com/the-code-review/to-boldly-log-debug-docker-apps-effectively-using-logs-options-tail-and-grep-53d2e655abcb).
Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40721348/7122892).